# How to mark checkbox as checked in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form, which I'm using to enter new service requests, as well as display and edit those requests. A part of this form is a list of labeled check-boxes, representing all countries.
When the existing request is displayed using this form, I need to be able to compare each country check-box with  a list of countries, which were initially selected, and marked each match as "checked". Another words, I need to restore the state of the check-box list to reflect what was checked originally. Should this type of logic handled in the controller by iterating over two nested loops (all countries Vs Selected countries), or is there a better way to do this using directives?

Here is my check-box list:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="selectbasic">What country is the data for</label>
                        <div>
                            <div style='height:100px;overflow-y:auto;border:solid 1px #aaa;'>
                                <div ng-repeat="item in countries">
                                    <input type='checkbox' ng-model="item.checked" ng-change="checkit()" />&nbsp;&nbsp; {{item.name}}
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And here is the part of my controller in which I may be able to handle this:

```
function getServiceRequestById(Id) {
            dataFactory.getServiceRequestById(Id)
                .success(function (request) {
                    $scope.OID = request.OID;
                    $scope.Description = request.Description;
                    $scope.RequestorName = request.RequestorName;
                    $scope.RequestorBusinessUnit = request.RequestorBusinessUnit;
                    $scope.CustomerName = request.CustomerName;
                    $scope.CscContactPerson = request.CscContactPerson;
                    $scope.IsWbsCodeAvailable = request.IsWbsCodeAvailable;
                    $scope.SalesforceIdNumber = request.SalesforceIdNumber;
                    $scope.ProjectCtv = request.ProjectCtv;
                    $scope.RequestedCompletionDate = request.RequestedCompletionDate;
                    $scope.ToBeUsedForCloudMigration = request.ToBeUsedForCloudMigration;
                    $scope.ToBeUsedForDatacenterMove = request.ToBeUsedForDatacenterMove;
                    $scope.ToBeUsedForServerRefresh = request.toBeUsedForServerRefresh;
                    $scope.DataRequirements = request.DataRequirements;
                    $scope.DataProtectionRequirements = request.DataProtectionRequirements;
                    $scope.ProjectedDataAvailability = request.ProjectedDataAvailability;
                    $scope.DiscoveryLeadName = request.DiscoveryLeadName;
                    $scope.SelectedCountries = request.SelectedCountries;
                    $scope.ManualDiscovery = request.ManualDiscovery;
                    $scope.AutomatedDiscovery = request.AutomatedDiscovery;
                    $scope.DataLoadUsingMasterTemplate = request.DataLoadUsingMasterTemplate;
                    $scope.DataLoadUsingAutomatedInterface = request.DataLoadUsingAutomatedInterface;
                    $scope.DataLoaderRequiresSitizenship = request.DataLoaderRequiresSitizenship;


                    var list = [];

                    var countries = request.SelectedCountries.split(',');

                    console.log('number of countries:  ' + countries.length);

                    console.log('countries[0]:  ' + countries[0] + ' --- ' + countries[1]);

                    $scope.checkit = function () {

                        for (var p in $scope.countries) {
                            if ($scope.countries[p].checked) {
                                list.push($scope.countries[p].name);

                                console.log("selected country:  " + $scope.countries[p].name + "  " + $scope.ProjectedDataAvailability);
                            }
                        } return list;
                    }
                    console.log('EditServiceRequestCtrl  request :   ' + request);

                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    console.log('getServiceRequestById returned error   ');
                });
        }
```

Comment: I don't see where you're assigning `$scope.countries`... I see a `var countries = ...`.

Comment: side note: Why assign all of those value types directly to $scope? It's more code and will cause issues if you try to modify them from within a child scope (e.g. in an ng-repeat).  `$scope.data = request;`  might be better for you overall

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function getServiceRequestById(Id) {
  dataFactory.getServiceRequestById(Id)
        .success(function (request) {
             $scope.data = request;
             $scope.selectecCountries = []; //make sure to clear selections
             $scope.countries = request.SelectedCountries.split(',');
        });
}

$scope.updateSelectedCountries = function() {
    var list = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.countries, function(country) {
       if(country.selected) list.push(country);
    });
    $scope.selectedCountries = list;
};
```

Then in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="country in countries track by $index">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="country.selected" ng-change="updateSelectedCountries()"/>
</div>

<h4>Demo Output</h4>
<pre>{{ selectedCountries | json}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting a list of countries, where each item has a "checked" member.

I'm also assuming you want to display all countries, not just the checked ones.

If that's the case, it's pretty simple.

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in countries">
        <input type='checkbox' ng-model="item.checked"  /> {{item.name}}
    </div>


  $scope.countries = [ {name: "USA", checked: true},
                       {name: "GBR", checked: false},
                       {name: "GER", checked: true}];
```

See a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tAhPs8oBCrJIX05fopVL?p=preview).

Comment: match:  var selectedcountries = request.SelectedCountries.split(',');

                    for (var ctr in $scope.countries) {
                        for (var index = 0; index < selectedcountries.length;index++) {
                            if ($scope.countries[ctr].name === selectedcountries[index]) {
                                console.log('Country Match Found:   ' + $scope.countries[ctr].name);
                                $scope.countries[ctr].checked = true; -- this does not actually mark it as checked
                            }
                        }
                    }

Comment: I updated the plunk to better reflect what I think you are doing with the selected countries.  I split something like "USA,GER" to ["USA","GER"] then update a "checked" member in an array of all countries.